# Multiple submit button in a form

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey I am very new to Web Programming. I have been learning PHP from the past few days and I am stuck at one thing.

I have a form tag in my code which has two submit buttons to manipulate on the data.
Since I can have only one action definition on my form tag, it can lead me to one page only. (Not very sure)

Now depending on the button clicked on the form, I want to load a different page.
One way is to check the button clicked in an if-else construct and then use echo '...' in the branches and show as if it is a different page. But it doesn't seem right for some reason. Can some one give me a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that there are other ways to submit a form other than clicking on a submit button - how about when you press enter in a text `input` for example? I think you should instead have a radiobutton/select/checkbox right at the end for this behavior rather than two submit buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use Javascript to switch the form's action depending on which control has been clicked. The following example uses the jQuery library:

```
<form id="theForm" action="foo.php">
...
    <input id="first" type="submit"/>
    <input id="second" type="submit"/>
</form>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theForm input").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.target.id == 'first') {
            $("#theForm").attr("action", "somePage.php");
        } else {
            $("#theForm").attr("action", "anotherPage.php");
        }
        alert($("#theForm").attr("action"));
        $("#theForm").submit(); 
    });
​});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/CMEqC/2/

Comment: This will completely break if JavaScript is not available (and there are enough people who have tripped over one to many JS bombs and installed NoScript out there that you shouldn't assume it will be). Doing it with server side branching is the right approach.

Comment: @David - This is true, I should have stated that in the answer. My solution is only good if his application *requires* that the user has Javascript.

Comment: This is great! I will be using JS at some point! Thanks! 
But Right now I have just made two forms for the time being so that I get two actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But it doesn't seem right for some reason.

That's wrong assumption.
Any other solution would be much worst.

Checking on the server side is the only reliable solution.
However `echo` in branches isn't necessary. There are a lot other ways.
To use `include` statement is most obvious one.

Comment: When we speak of the MVC architecture, I fell this isn't right and besides it's a lame way of doing things.

Comment: @Gooner LOL that's most funny comment I've ever seen. You do not understand what you talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

just as a reference... int HTML5 buttons can redefine the form's action,method,type etc. http://w3schools.com/html5/tag_button.asp for me, that's a good way to control a form :)

Comment: This answer might be useful in 2030 when browsers which haven't implemented that feature probably won't be common enough to worry about.

Comment: i know..that's why i said "as a reference"... i think it's a good feature though

Answer (score -2):

to add another solution based on @karim79's, since it's tagged with PHP:

```
<form id="theForm" action="foo.php">
...
    <input id="first" name="button" value="first" type="submit"/>
    <input id="second" name="button" value="second" type="submit"/>
</form>​
```

in your foo.php, do something like this:

```
<?php
$submit = isset($_GET['button']) ? trim($_GET['button']) : '';

if($submit == 'first')
{
   header('Location: somePage.php');
}
else if($submit == 'second')
{
   header('Location: anotherPage.php');
}
?>
```

Summary:
to be able to read on your button (2 submit buttons), you need to add `name` on each one. To make it simple, just use the same name on both. Then, add different `value`. Next, you need **to know what button is being clicked by checking what value is sent on that particular button**.

Comment: That's going to discard all the form data when it redirects, but it otherwise identical to the approach the question describes.