# How to know which button has clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, submit

i have html form

i am using `<a href="#" onclick="document.aa.submit()">` instead of submit button

my code will explain my problem better..

```
<html>
<form name="aa" action="aa.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="2">
<a href="#" onclick="document.aa.submit()">Delete</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.aa.submit()">Move</a>
</form>
</html>
```

aa.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

results

```
Array ( [posts] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )
```

Now the question is:

How to know user clicked on delete or move?

## Note:

i know if i used `<input submit>` it will fixes the problem

but i can't use submit button for some reason

## Note 2

the question is how to detect it by php.

Example:

```
    Array ( [posts] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ['submit'=>'delete']) ) 

if('delete'){
mysql_query("delete from...")
}
else{
mysql_query("update/move ....");
}
```

Comment: Use an ID tag on the a elements? Posting the id and retrieving it with the php form.

Comment: Use ID tag to differentiate between elements !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple submit button in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540585/multiple-submit-button-in-a-form)

Comment: my quetion is how to detect it by php, not by html, example Array ( [posts] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ['submit'=>'delete']) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some tweaks to the form so the Post value knows which option you are submitting

```
  <form name="aa" action="aa.php" id='aa' method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="2">
    <a href="#" onclick="submit_function(this)" rel="delete">Delete</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="submit_function(this)" rel="move">Move</a>
        <input id="submit_type" type="hidden" name="task">
        </form>
```

in js with jquery

```
function submit_function( item ){
    if( item.rel == 'move')
    {
    document.getElementById('submit_type').value ='move'
    }
    else if( item.rel == 'delete')
    {
    document.getElementById('submit_type').value ='delete'
    }

    document.getElementById('aa').submit()

    }
```

in php

```
 if( $_POST['task'] == 'move' )
{
//do move stuff
}

    if( $_POST['task'] == 'delete' )
{
//do delete stuff
}
```

Comment: This is good solution, but why you did't short your javascript function to document.getElementById('submit_type').value=item and use it as <a onclick="function('delete')"> your code is better than mine, i wish if you improve the javascript function, i am waiting for your modifiction

Comment: good point. get rid of the if statements and change the line to document.getElementById('submit_type').value = item.rel

Comment: No need for ifs, just set the value: `document.aa.submit_type.value = item.rel;`

Answer (score 1):

Only PHP?... No javascript?   If you are using javascript I would suggest the idea of using a button that calls some javascript to submit the form instead of a link, it might give you better results as you could also make some calls to set some hidden fields of the form before it is submitted.  Also, why is submit broken?

Take a look at the following page for know how on how to use hidden fields.

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php

upon post you should be able to get the hidden field as if the user had submitted it and then do your computation in the php instead of the html.

Comment: This is a fantastic idea, the idea is: on click on delete button, create a hidden input ( named delete ) Example: <a onclick="create('delete')"> and ofcourse now i will be able to know which button has been clicked by php

Comment: Please thumbs up if the answer helped you. I am new to StackOverflow and need the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<html>
<form name="aa" action="aa.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="2">
<a href="#" onclick="document.aa.action='delete';document.aa.submit()">Delete</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.aa.action='move';document.aa.submit()">Move</a>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: This will work perfectly unless i process data in one file, Not multiple action files, please see my solution if you intersted this question

Comment: Obviously, @codefactor's idea to name hidden field the same as form's attribute is not good :) I'm thought that he is about changing value of hidden element, not an attribute of `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can even get rid of the `onclick` event in your tags and just add the following jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert($(this).html()) // Replace this line with the one below for your code
        // document.aa.submit($(this).html())   
    });
});​
```

The `$(this).html()` will return the innerhtml of the click `a` tag. e.g "Delete or "Move". You can then use this in your php to identify the clicked linke

Comment: i am sorry i don't use jquery

Comment: shame. would have suited your problem perfectly

Comment: hhh, i have a clothes suite my size, but i don't wear it because of their colors

Comment: Your choice. But since your using javascript I didn't see the harm of using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
<script>
function createInput(action){
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "action");
input.setAttribute("value", action);
document.getElementById("forsm").appendChild(input);
document.aa.submit();
}
</script>

<html>
<form name="aa" id="forsm" action="aa.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="posts[]" value="2">
<a href="#" id="delete" onclick="createInput('delete');">Delete</a>
<a href="#" id="move" onclick="createInput('move');">Move</a>
</form>
</html>
```

results

Array ( [posts] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [action] => move )

## Many Thanks for Rusty Weber, That gived me the idea

Comment: I think codefactor's solution is much better because the field always will be available. It would be useful in some cases. You can, of course, wrap his solution into function. Also, `createInput`, I think, is not a good name for the function that submits form too...

Comment: The codefactor's solution is useful if i process data in multiple files, but i use one file to process data, i cannot use multiple action files, as well as i use about 12 submit button, that's mean i will need to create 12 file!

Comment: `CreateInput ` does seem like a very generic name, maybe reconsider reanaming `SubmitWithHiddenValue`.  I would also normally agree with Codefactor's solution as dealing with only one php file for your entire solution is prone to bugs and isn't exactly robust.  It really depends on the type of action being taken and how complex you need to make the program.