# Sending POST data from one form with 2 buttons

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can I send the POST data from my form to two different pages depending on which post button is clicked?

My "Export" button sends the POST data to 'export.php', but the "Graphique" button must send the POST data to the 'graphique.php' page.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="TCAgregat" class="TCAgregat" action="export.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="daco" value="<?php echo $DConso; ?>"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="CNS" value="<?php echo $CNewCentres; ?>"></input>

    <input type=submit border="0" class="EXP" name="exp" value="EXPORT" />  
    <input type=submit border="0" class="DCB" name="dcb" value="GRAPHIQUE" />
</form>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put them in separate forms?

Comment: Or use javascript or acnhor tags with query strings

Comment: Change form action on button click.

Comment: You can use JavaScript, to evaluate which button was pressed and changed the "action" page accordingly, before submitting.

Comment: Duplicate: [Multiple submit button in a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540585/multiple-submit-button-in-a-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change form action on button click:

```
$("form").on("click", ":submit", function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).attr('action', $(this).data('action'));
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type=submit data-action="export.php" value="EXPORT" />
<input type=submit data-action="graphics.php" value="GRAPHIQUE" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FAnq9/

Answer (score 3):

Say `action="handler.php"` and then write `handler.php` something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {
        include('export.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['dcb'])) {
        include('graphique.php');
    } else {
        // Default state / error handling
    }
?>
```

Comment: just a point. what if he wants to send the data to both the files and not just one?

Comment: Then he can include both of them in the same branch of the `if` statement. Nothing in the question remotely suggests that he might want to though.

Comment: he google translated it probably. but the 1st line `How can send the same POST data totwo different pages` to me it seemes like he is trying to post on two different page at the same time.... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to rewrite the `action` of the form, then `submit()`.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way (which I wouldn't recommend as it introduces an unnecessary dependency on JS), then calling `submit()` is redundant. Just don't cancel the default action of the form in the first place.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer. Should have at least given an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged it with jQuery, here is a solution:

```
$(input[type="submit"]).click(function(){
 var but = $(this).val();
 var action = '';
 if(but == 'EXPORT')
 {
    action = 'export.php';
 }
 else if(but == 'GRAPHIQUE')
 {
    action = 'graphique.php';
 }

 $('form').attr('action', action);

})
```